# Как создавать переменные в print() Python?

Tags: python, print

Можно ли и если да, то как, создавать переменные в print() Python? Хочу ради интереса посокращать код, но, например, когда в print используется одна переменная более одного раза, то не получится отделаться print(input()), как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Очень похоже, что вы ерундой занимаетесь. Сэкономить несколько символов во вред читаемости кода - плохая идея.

Comment: Плохая идея. Но есть [valrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) и есть лямбды (в которые можно поместить почти любые вычисления).

Comment: Но всё-таки могли бы показать пример кода, о котором идёт речь )